# Replace c-style cast (long&) in c++

Tags: c++

In a source code, I got this c-style cast :

```
unsigned long test = 0;
long & truc = (long&)test;
```

I assume that `&truc` take the address of test with `long` type.

How I can do that in C++?

Thanks!

Comment: Use std::addressof

Comment: `(long &)test` obtains a reference to a `long`, which refers to `test.`   It does not compute the address.    Although it uses C-like "cast" syntax, it is not a c-style cast, since C does not support reference types.  In C, your code would not compile.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<long&>(test);`

Comment: @rak007 there is no adress in OPs code, their assumption is wrong

Comment: @Peter -- it's not a valid cast in C, but it **is** a "c-style cast". That term refers to syntax, and it distuinguishes this code from the four C++-style casts (`static_cast`, `const_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, and `reinterpret_cast`).

Comment: @PeteBecker - fair enough.   Although it does seem a bit odd to label a construct that would be diagnosed as an error by any C compiler as "c-style".

Comment: @Peter no more than an `class myClass{ void foo(); }; myClass myArray[10]` is a C-style array of C++ only type, to distinguish it from `std::array<myClass, 10> myArray`

Comment: @Caleth - difference is that it is possible to envisage a declaration like `myClass myArray[10]` being valid in C (e.g. if `myClass` is a `typedef` for a type that may be specified in C).   It is pretty difficult to envisage a way in which a construct `long &truc = (long &)test` can be valid C.     In any event, my point is that the OP asked the question in a way that suggested the code was C that needed to be re-expressed in C++  (and also assumed it was computing an address, which it isn't) when in reality it is not valid C at all.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "how [can I] do that in C++"? You've already done it! [It works!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06fa6d7992bea15c)

Putting aside for a moment the potentially questionable aliasing, a cast to reference type is perfectly valid and does what you expect.

More generally, such a cast might be used to transform an expression into one with the type of its base, without *copying* the object it describes:

```
Derived d;
Base& b = (Base&)d;
```

Although to be idiomatic you'd prefer a `static_cast` in such a case:

```
Derived d;
Base& b = static_cast<Base&>(d);
```

Indeed, the way a C-style cast works in C++ is that, in this particular case (cast to reference of a related type), the C-style cast *is* a `static_cast`.

This is also a common pattern with `dynamic_cast`, which works with a pointer type:

```
assert(dynamic_cast<T*>(ptr) != nullptr);
```

but also reference type:

```
try {
   dynamic_cast<T&>(*ptr);
}
catch (const std::bad_cast&) {}
```

Long story short, there's nothing wrong or weird about a cast to reference type.

That being said, I would avoid questionable conversions like `unsigned long` to `long` — it's possible that this aliasing is technically well-defined, but I would have to dive into the standard to be sure, and that in my opinion is reason enough to avoid it.

One upside of switching to `static_cast` is that, if the conversion is *not* permitted, you'll be informed. You can then switch in turn to `reinterpret_cast` and go on with your questionable aliasing. ;)

---

#### Addendum

> Aliasing between `long` and `unsigned long` is allowed ([basic.lval] 10), as long as the value is in range for both. But yeah, best avoided. – [Sneftel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/787480/sneftel)

Comment: As long as the value is not too long for `long` or for `unsigned long` if you're using `unsigned long`